# Edit Case from Sites

Tags: visualforce, case, force.com-sites, site.com, case-object

I created a VF and a controller to edit few fields on case object. 
It is working fine when I preview it and pass the case Id, 
But when I open it from the site the input texts are gone. I am able to display the data but from but wherever there was input of any kind it has disappeared.
I checked the field level security but is there anything different for Case object that needs to be done to make its fields visible to guest users.

```
public without sharing class Case_Verify_Email {
public String urlId{get;set;}    
public List<Case> cs {get;set;}

public Case_Verify_Email(){    
    this.urlId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    Case c = [Select PickupLocationId__r.id from Case where Id=:urlId];
    cs = new List<Case>();
    cs = [Select id, CaseNumber,Status,Phone_Number__c,Vehicle_ready_for_pick_up__c, Vehicle_Runs__c, Reason_Vehicle_is_not_running__c,
         Vehicle_has_keys__c, Will_they_be_making_keys__c, Address_Verified__c, Different_Address__c,
         Pickup_Address__c, Pickup_City__c, Pickup_State__c, Pickup_Zip__c  
         from Case where PickupLocationId__r.id =: c.PickupLocationId__r.id AND Status != 'Closed'];

}

public PageReference Submit(){               

    update cs;

    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/VVThankYou');
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
}

}  
  <apex:page controller="Case_Verify_Email">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >                          
                <apex:repeat value="{!cs}" var="c">
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    Case No : {!c.CaseNumber}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Please Verify that the vehicle is at your address {!c.Pickup_Address__c}, {!c.Pickup_City__c}, {!c.Pickup_State__c}, {!c.Pickup_Zip__c}
                        <br/> If not what address
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!c.Address_Verified__c}"/>
                        <br/> <apex:inputField value="{!c.Different_Address__c}"/>
                    </td>                      
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Vehicle has keys ?
                        <br/>If not will you be making keys    
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!c.Vehicle_has_keys__c}"/>
                        <br/><apex:inputField value="{!c.Will_they_be_making_keys__c}"/>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Vehicle Runs?
                        <br/> If not what is wrong
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!c.Vehicle_Runs__c}"/>
                        <br/><apex:inputField value="{!c.Reason_Vehicle_is_not_running__c}"/>
                    </td>                                              
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Is this vehicle ready to be picked up
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!c.Vehicle_ready_for_pick_up__c}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <br/><br/>
                </table>
                </apex:repeat>                                        
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Submit}" value="Submit"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: Could you share your code? I guess you have already enabled FLS for guest user's profile. Try using custom controller in without sharing mode.

Comment: @RahulSharma Tried without sharing as well still the same

Comment: @RahulSharma added the controller

Comment: @RahulSharma added

Comment: You've checked the object CRUD permissions also?

Comment: Public sites: `You can grant “Read” and “Create” permissions on all standard objects except products, price books, and ideas; and “Read,” “Create,” “Edit,” and “Delete” on all custom objects.` [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_public_access_settings.htm&type=0).  There are workarounds involving controllers w/o sharing

Comment: @cropredy But I am already using without sharing still unable to edit the fields. What workaround is there ?